# Bounding the Frobenius norm of orthogonalised matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-norms

**Context**: I am trying to show the convergence of an optimization method which includes orthogonalization in the update step.

**Problem**: Let's say I have real matrices $A, B \in \mathcal{R}^{n xm}$. If important, $n \gg m$ and I also know that the rank of the matrices is $m$. I orthogonalize both matrices using Gram-Schmidt. Let's say the resulting matrices are $Q_A$ and $Q_B$. I need to bound the square of the Frobenius norm of the difference of the matrices ($\|Q_A - Q_B\|_F^2$). Since there might be multiple orthogonalization, I am interested in the upper bound on the minimum of this quantity.

**Question**: Is there anyway I can bound $\|Q_A - Q_B\|_F^2$ using $\|A-B\|_F^2$ or any function of $A, B$.

Comment: Are you sure the squared Frobenius norm of the difference is the best metric?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am pretty sure bounding the Frobenius norm is sufficient for my case. However, it might not be necessary. If you know this relationship (bounding one metric on the original matrix implies a similar bound on the orthogonalized one) for a different metric, please let me know. I can try to work out rest of the theory using the metric you suggest.

Comment: The columns of $Q_A$ and $Q_B$ form orthonormal bases. Hence, why not try to find the angles that rotate one basis into the other? That would be a vector of angles. A vector norm might do.